# How to get a site to accept inserted recaptcha answer code

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, recaptcha

currently I'm doing some scraping, and tryin (and failing) to get passed a recaptcha on a specific website( https://iowa.igovsolution.com/iboponline/Lookups/Lookup_Individual.aspx ). I'm using Seleneium Chromium to move through the website, and DeathByCaptcha to get the answer code, which I then insert code into the g-recaptcha-response. Though after filling in the rest of the form and pressing enter, it doesn't registered that the recaptcha was 'finished.'

What I've noticed about this sight--which is different then the others I've dealt with. is that this site makes two separate post request, a 'verify captcha' post request where it sends the recaptcha answer code, and the post request with the general data, rather then a single post request with the general data, and the information I fill out into the form. I was wondering what I needed to do(or if it's not possible to do with Selenium).

I have done some research, but I can't find very much that is about my issue.

The code I use to insert the answer code into the g-recaptcha-response is this(and I know it works at inserting it since I've checked to make sure it actually puts it in there and it does. I've also used this method of getting passed recaptchas on other sites):

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "' + str(key) + '"')
```

Comment: That looks right to me. You should pause it there and inspect that element to make sure it worked.

Comment: @pguardiario I have paused it there to check if element has inputted itself into the inner text--and it has.

Comment: I'm looking at that now, there's a callback and if you follow it, a verifycaptcha function which you can call with execute_script